# Git GUI on Windows not seeing .git folder from Samba share

Tags: linux, samba, git, virtualbox, vagrant

**THE SCENARIO**
I am using Vagrant,Windows environment and running Ubuntu inside the virtual box for my development work. I have setup an instance of Samba server and I run the I access the virtual machine through vagrant and Git Bash and run the command 
`net use A: \\192.168.91.11\www vagrant /persistent:no /user:vagrant`
in windows cmd. This creates a virtual drive in Windows and I can access all the linux files from windows. Git related operations run fine with the Bash CLI. I want to try and setup a Git GUI like TortoiseGit.

**THE PROBLEM**
I am not able to see the `.git` folder inside the virtual drive.
I have already tried to change the folder options to show hidden folders, show archives, remove the readonly on the drive, but still the `.git` folder remains hidden. The `.git` folder is visible when I run the ll command on the CLI. However it remains hidden when I access the virtual drive from windows.
I wonder if there even is a way to use a gui in this setup. Excuse the long description but I need some advice here. If there is any other way to implement a GUI in this setup, I'm all ears! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My setup is not exactly the same but may be useful to you:
I've got a Windows machine with my Git checkout e.g. C:\MyProject that I'm using TortoiseGit with. I've shared this folder in Windows: right click/properties/sharing. I'm running a Ubuntu VM that is accessing my share for building/debugging my project.

To access the share on Linux I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

I added my share to fstab so that it would connect every time the machine came up:

```
sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

Adding the following line to the end of the file:

```
//<COMPUTER NAME>/MyProject /home/<USERNAME>/MyProject cifs defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0700,dir_mode=0700,noperm,vers=2.1,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials 0 0
```

You then need to create the file `/root/.smbcredentials` to store your Windows username and password. Adding the following to the file:

```
username=<MY WINDOWS USERNAME>
password=<MY WINDOWS PASSWORD>
```

Change the permissions on the `.smbcredentials` file so that only root can access this:

```
sudo su & chmod 600 /root/.smbcredentials
```

You should then be able to mount with:

```
sudo mount -a
```

This is allowing me to access all my files on Windows while still be able to natively build and debug my application from within my Linux VM. I'm sure you could do something similar with your vagrant setup.